# How do you say ‘What's it like living in Mexico?’ in Castilian Spanish?

Tags: traducción, españa

How do you say ‘What's it like living in Mexico’ in Castilian Spanish?

> Que es vivir en Mexico?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way of saying it is:

> ¿**Cómo** es vivir en México?

What you wrote can be translated as: *What is living in Mexico?*

Comment: I suppose this can be said too: "¿Cómo se vive en México?" o "¿Qué tal se vive en México?"

Comment: @albertomegia:  No.  Neither choice sounds appropriate for this context.